# Files inside Alias folder not accessible

Tags: apache2

In my apache2.conf I have an alias setup like this:

```
Alias /cake/ /var/www-cake/repo
<Directory /var/www-cake/repo>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

inside the /var/www-cake/repo directory I just have 1 file that is `index.php`

when I go to http://linux-server/cake/ I get a directory listing that shoes the index.php file. When I click on the file it takes me to `http://linux-server/cake/index.php` in which I get a 404 page not found error.

What do I need to do to make the files accessible?

Answer (score 3):

I changed my code to this:

```
Alias /cake /var/www-cake/repo
<Directory /var/www-cake/repo>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Notice the trailing slash is now removed from the Alias. I do not know why this made a difference I was just trying random things and this one seemed to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Insider your directory block trying updating `Options` to: `Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks` After your edits make sure to restart the Apache service.

Secondly make sure you don't have any conflicting directives in a .htaccess file inside `/var/www-cake/repo/`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your options and it didn't make a difference. I also did not add any .htaccess file to /var/www-cake/repo. Is there possibly a step I am missing?

Comment: Last thing I can think of is permissions issue - but you would probably see something like "403: Forbidden" and not a 404.

Comment: Yeah, and another strange part is that if there is a index.php which it shows in the directory listing, then why is it showing the directory listing at all, shouldn't it just load the index.php file.

Comment: please see my answer :)